# WKPDF system error?

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, internal-server-error

I'm trying to figure out what PDF files are being generated by my WKPDF.php file.

Here's the email I get when they fail (which is every time):

```
WKPDF system error: <pre>Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[=============>                                              ] 23%
[===================>                                        ] 32%
[============================>                               ] 47%
[============================>                               ] 48%
[===============================>                            ] 52%
Warning: SSL error ignored
[===============================>                            ] 52%
[===============================>                            ] 53%
[=================================>                          ] 55%
[==================================>                         ] 57%
[===================================>                        ] 59%
[=======================================>                    ] 66%
[========================================>                   ] 68%
[===========================================>                ] 72%
[==============================================>             ] 78%
[================================================>           ] 81%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
[>                                                           ] Preparing
[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
Done
</pre>

/dashboard/submit/overview

Array
(
    [info1] => pdf
    [attached_stuff] => 0
    [more_info] =>
    [stackoverflow] => exact
    [other_data] =>
    [sample_fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => option1
            [1] => option2
            [2] => option3
        )
    [test_option] => Url
    [last_test] => ASC
)
```

Here's the line from my PHP file that's sending the error in case that helps:

```
if(strpos(strtolower($this->pdf['stderr']),'error')!==false)throw new Exception('WKPDF system error: <pre>'.$this->pdf['stderr'].'</pre>');
```

A bunch of people have talked about similar issues that are related to using WKPDF with an SSL, but I don't think that's causing my problems since it says the SSL error was ignored...  Any help would be really appreciated.  Whenever I try doing it, there appears to be a 500 error occurring but I can't find any reason for that to be happening...

Let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Search for **http://** protocol in your html , it should be **https**.

**Example**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Georgia|Asap|Arial|Helvetica|Arial+Black|Gadget|Comic+Sans+MS|Impact|Charcoal|Tahoma|Geneva|Verdana|Geneva|Courier+New|Courier|serif">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?subset=arabic&family=Cairo|Amiri|Changa|Mada|Lateef|Baloo+Bhaijaan|Reem+Kufi|Lalezar|Scheherazade|El+Messiri|Aref+Ruqaa|Harmattan|Lemonada|Mirza|Rakkas|Katibeh|Jomhuria">
```